# no module named numpy even after installing it

Tags: linux, numpy, server, pip

I am using numpy in a python file. I am trying to execut this file on a remote linux server. I have installed **pip** and **numpy** without being root as mentioned in this post:
[https://gist.github.com/saurabhshri/46e4069164b87a708b39d947e4527298](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false)

Despite the fact that pip and numpy were both installed successfully I still get :

```
import numpy

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have tried to create a virtual environment but when doing that I get:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

ps: when I type `./pip list`  this is the main stuff I get:

```
numpy              1.16.3 
pip                19.1.1
```

and I have both: `Python 2.7.15rc1` and `Python 3.6.7`

Answer (score 2):

You should check if you installed NumPy for Python version you actually try to use. The easiest way is to list two directories:

- `ls -la ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
- `ls -la ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`

and check if there are NumPy files (directories may differ due to your version of Python). If there are none, you may want to install them:

Python 2.x:

1. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
2. `python get-pip.py --user`
3. `echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`
4. `source ~/.bashrc`
5. `pip install numpy --user`

Python 3.x:

1. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
2. `python3 get-pip.py --user`
3. `echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`
4. `source ~/.bashrc`
5. `pip3 install numpy --user`

Comment: in python 2 I do have NumPy packages, but in Python3 I don't. I have tried to install them as you mentioned but once I get to 5th command I get: `ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`

Answer (score 0):

the 3rd command should be :

```
echo "export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

bash should use pip from ~/.local/bin, not from /usr/local/bin. So I placed .local before every other entry in the path.